# How to handle Firebase Auth from mobile app and node API

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am building a REST API in node.js which needs to use Flutter and a React web app as their clients. The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure where to handle the authorization. Both Flutter and React have a prebuilt "UI" from Firebase that doesen't even need to be connected to the backend. But also there is an option to just take the password and email from the forms and send them to my API which sends them to Firebase via a post request. The flow should be this, a user signs up with Firebase and is created, while that is happening he is also being "signed" up on my API so I can append and store data in his account.
I only need Firebase as an authorization layer, I feel that at this point in time I can't build anything comparable in terms of security when it comes to the authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with Firebase Authentication accounts on your backend, then you will need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).  In particular, what you need to do is have the client app send the ID token provided by the SDK and [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) so your backend can do things on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to avoid implementing integration with Firebase in the client side, and do it only in the server side. You can use [Firebase-Admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) to integrate with Firebase in your node.js server. Then, the sign up/in request will be via your API.

In this way, your clients don't depend on 3rd party and all of the library updates should be in your server.